# Upgrading computer RAM

Tags: ram, swap

I am planning to upgrade the computer RAM: will I have to reinstall Ubuntu? I am asking this question because of the swap partition: if I double the RAM do I have to double the swap partition too?

Comment: Just add your RAM, your box will detect it as will your OS. Personally I always run memtest before trusting any RAM change, and a swap change may only be required IF you're using hibernate (where it must be large enough to store all of RAM + whatever is currently in swap), but you can add additional swap via swapfile (ie. swapfile + swap partition) if needs be for most release of Ubuntu (you didn't specify), but if you're not hibernating, you can ignore touching swap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### No.

Your computer will boot without any problems (provided you installed the right kind of RAM, etc.).

Afterwards, take a minute to double the swap size as well. You may even wait until you experience memory problems. If you have a little more time, get rid of the swap partition altogether, and create a swap file.

Comment: Most recent versions of Ubuntu not using a swap partition anymore, use a swap file.

Comment: @crip659 I hadn't caught that - good point. I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: There is no need to double swap size at all unless hibernation is used.